# Is there a way to simulate app being killed?

Tags: calabash-ios

I was wondering if it is possible to simulate a killed app (manually we double press Home button and swipe the app window off the screen) using Calabash-ios framework. And then relaunch the app.
Thank you.

Comment: By default, iOS won't allow app to be relaunched automatically.

Answer (score 0):

No.  There is no way to do what you describe:  double press Home + a swipe to quit.

However, Calabash does try to simulate a graceful shutdown with `calabash_exit`.

http://calabashapi.xamarin.com/ios/Calabash/Cucumber/Core.html#calabash_exit-instance_method

In the cucumber client, I can't think of a nice way to do a `calabash_exit` and a relaunch in a Step.  I can think of at least one not-so nice way, but I am not sure it would work.